# Grails/java single resource pooling thread queue

Tags: java, grails, threadpool

I'm trying to setup a server that provides true-random number from a device, `Quantis - Quantum Random Number Generator`. I built the web application with the Grails framework, running on `Tomcat` server on `Ubuntu`.

Since there's only 1 device, I have to schedule the threads that accesses it, correct? So I set semaphores (with 1 resource) on the functions (`ReadInt, ReadDouble, ReadFloat`) that call this device. The object that contains these functions is called `Quantis` stored in the Java Source Packages for the Grails app, it's implemented as a singleton; the controllers will then call and instance of this object and it's functions. Then each of those function will call the Quantis Library on the system to read the stream from the device <- now this is the critical zone. I need to make sure there's only one request at one time to this device.

The semaphores seem to work fine. But if I refresh the page (retrieving the stream of random numbers) really fast (like +/- 10 times) it will crash. I have "blindly" tried many approaches from the internet including grails `executors` but nothing seems to work (however I might have not implemented them correctly, really).

Does any one have any idea how I can solve this?

Here's my code for one of the functions: (they all look about the same style, but calling different system library functions when retrieving the data)

```
    private static final Semaphore ticket = new Semaphore(1, true);
    ...
    public int ReadInt(int min, int max) throws QuantisException {
        while (true) {
            try {
                ticket.acquire();
                int data = QuantisReadScaledInt(deviceType.getType(), deviceNumber, min, max);
                ticket.release();
                return data;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            } catch (QuantisException ex) {
                ticket.release();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "*it will crash*" is a poor description of what happens. Any exception? What happens exactly?

Second, are you sure you need to synchronize the access to the API. If it provides a Java API, there's a good chance that this API already is synchronized, and that your semaphore isn't needed.

Third, if you acquire a semaphore, you should release it in a finally block. This guarantees that it's released, whatever happens inside the try block:

```
ticket.acquire();
try {
    ...
}
catch (...) 
finally {
    ticket.release();
}
```

Fourth: I don't understand the point of the `while(true)` loop. The only time it loops is when there is an InterruptedException. And an InterruptedException is precisely used to signal a thread that it should stop executing ASAP. So your method should throw this exception instead of swallowing it.

Finally, you should learn Java naming conventions and stick to them. Methods start with a lower-case letter.

Provided you really need to synchronize access, here is thus how I would rewrite the method:

```
public int readInt(int min, int max) throws QuantisException, InterruptedException {
    ticket.acquire();
    try {
        return quantisReadScaledInt(deviceType.getType(), deviceNumber, min, max);
    }
    finally {
        ticket.release();
    }
}
```

If you want to ensure that only one thread has access to the native library functions, use such a class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SingleThreadAccess {
    public static final SingleThreadAccess INSTANCE = new SingleThreadAccess();

    private ExecutorService executor;

    // to be called by ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()
    public void init() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    // to be called by ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()
    public void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(2L,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    public int readInt(int min, int max) throws QuantisException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<Integer> task = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws QuantisException {
                return quantisReadScaledInt(deviceType.getType(), deviceNumber, min, max);
            }
        };
        Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(task);
        try {
            future.get();
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            unwrap(e);
        }
    }

    private void unwrap(ExecutionException e) throws QuantisException {
        Throwable t = e.getCause();
        if (t instanceof QuantisException) {
            throw (QuantisException) t;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nizet, Thank you so much for the input. By saying crash, I mean, when there are multiple connection requesting to the device, the tomcat server will crash, and the log outputs:
<pre>
libusb:warning [libusb_open] internal signalling write failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f095e06e288, pid=9879, tid=139678215476992
# ...
</pre>
But when i implement the semaphore, it actually works fine until we test it with multiple connection sending (refreshing) the requests really really fast.
Thank you, I'll try what you just said..

Comment: oh and almost forgot: no, the api is not a java api. It's a C library with a java wrapper. and from what i see, i dont think it's synchronized. Also, before i implemented the semaphore at all, it crashes straight away, if i refresh the request really fast for only 3 times. Since there are no exception, and the error message says (at the very end) that the error comes from outside of the JVM, I'm quite sure it comes from the C library, because multiple are requesting the device while it's locked by the current thread using it.

Comment: I'm not an expert in native code, but maybe tye C library, even when only one thread calls it at once, can't be used at all by multiple threads. In this case, you should dedicate one thread to the use of the API. If that's the case (but it should be documented!), and you don't know how to do, ask another question, and I'll be glad to anwer.

Comment: oh gosh, thank you so much nizet. Yes, I dont know how to do what you just said, and it IS what i'm trying to achieve, I just dont know whether what I'm doing right now is right or not. Am i?
I know for sure the threads in the C library is not syncrhonized, cause it simply calls the device only, and gets it's return.
another thing is, is it possible that tomcat creates more than 1 servlet and the thread synchronization only happens within 1 particular servlet? cause I cant seem to understand why the code above (that you gave) still crashes when i refresh really fast.

Comment: If tomcat servlet does behave like that, do you know how to restrict it to only create one servlet, and just queue the request to use that one servlet? 
If not, can we just go with what you just suggested? 
thank you so much, nizet

Comment: Read the edited answer. And also read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question

Comment: Tomcat creates only one servlet instance per servlet declaration, but it's irrelevant. What is important is the number of threads using the method. And a singleton is a singleton, so unless your singleton isn't one, there should be no synchronization problem.

Comment: thank you so much, nizet. it really does seem to be what i need - but i dont know how to use it my program, i've never worked with all this concurrent programming before. Would you like to read the 2 java files that are involved in this? 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ey1er57xjpbble6/MainController.groovy
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbavup9pyyyd3f4/Quantis.java
Thank you so much for helping me, nizet

Comment: I removed all the synchronization work from the files, so those two files are what it should look like without trying to all the semaphore stuff. The code where i tried implementing Quantis.java as a singleton is also still there, but i'm sure it's not right.

Comment: To read an int, call SingleThreadAccess.INSTANCE.readInt(1, 3). All the other public methods should look like the `readInt` method. That way, everything something must be done, a task is submitted to a single thread, and the future gives the result back when the single thread has executed the task. The init and shutdown methods should be called when the application is deployed and undeployed, respectively (using a ServletContextListener declared in the web.xml). Read the javadoc for more information.

Comment: Thank you nizet, that's really alot clear to me now. One thing left, when you said "using a ServletContextListener declared in the web.xml", do you mean i have to declare it myself? or is it something already done there? If i have to do it, how is that done? i have no idea what this is, so i dont even know where to start to google. Sorry for my silly questions, nizet. and thank you so much..

Comment: google for "ServletContextListener web.xml", and you'll find. You have to create an implementation and declare it in web.xml.

Comment: I found this link explaining it:
http://www.javabeat.net/tips/178-servletcontextlistener-example.html
is there any part of it that i have to modify (except for the package name ofcourse) ? 
I'm so sorry for asking this dumb nizet. this is the first time ever i've built a web application. ever.